# How to fix search view working where given field able to searchable?

Tags: odoo, enhanced-ecommerce, odoo-14

The below code should apply search by name, contact, and email. but it's not working as expected. I would like to know.
in the image attached, the only search is applicable for the name. but not email and contact.

```
<record id="merchant_search" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">ecommece_advance.merchant.search</field>
    <field name="model">ecommece_advance.merchant</field>
    <field name="type">search</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <search string="Merchants">
            <field name="name" string="Merchant Name"/>
            <field name="contact"/>
            <field name="email" string="Email" filter_domain="[('email', 'ilike', self)]"/>
            <separator/>
            <group expand="0" string="Group By">
                <filter string="Name" name="Name" domain="[]" context="{'group_by': 'name'}"/>
            </group>
        </search>
    </field>
</record>
```

//model fields

```
name        = fields.Char( required=True)
email       = fields.Char(required=True)
address     = fields.Char()
website     = fields.Char()
latitude    = fields.Float(digits=(3,6))
longitude   = fields.Float(digits=(3,6))
contact     = fields.Char(required=True)
alternative_contact = fields.Char()
```

[image: search view]

[image: search failed with ss but search result exists]

Comment: If these filters are not added, you should check that your xml file is called in the data section in your manifest.py file of your module : 'data': [ 'view/merchants.xml',
Otherwise, if this record was already existing in another module, consider inherit it from its original module :

Answer (score 1):

Let's add these filters to check that your xml file is loaded :

```
<filter string="Name" name="Name" domain="[]" context="{'group_by': 'name'}"/>
<filter string="Email" name="Email" domain="[]" context="{'group_by': 'email'}"/>
<filter string="Contact" name="Contact" domain="[]" context="{'group_by': 'contact'}"/>
```

If these filters are not added, you should check that your xml file is called in the data section in your **manifest**.py file of your module :
'data': [
'view/merchants.xml',

Otherwise, if this record was already existing, consider inherit it from its original module and use xpath to insert your new fields in  :

```
  <record id="merchant_search" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="original_module.merchant_search" />
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//search" position="inside">           
          <field name="email">email</field>
          <field name="contact">contact</field>
        </xpath>
   </record>
```

Comment: i am not going to group by. i should be search by email and contact also.